# How to say, "In any case...."

Tags: expressions, choix-de-mot

To say in French, "In any case...", I have seen both, " Dans tous les cas..." Or "De toute façon". Which is better, or do the two examples say something different, or is there a better way to say this?

Comment: Both are correct. "Dans tous les cas" would be used if different cases can be deduced from the context. "De toute façon"  corresponds to "Whatever".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two phrases are similar. However, "Dans tous les cas," like "In any case" in English, places more emphasis on a statement being true in *multiple cases*. I would expect to hear it in a slightly more formal or didactic setting.
"De toute façon", like "Anyway" in English, implies disregard for the information that precedes it. I would expect to hear it in a less formal setting.

Answer (score 1):

*En tout cas* an almost word to word translation can also be used for *in any case* to state a conclusion not depending on the preceding argument...